# div сразу по div

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть 4 блока:

```html
<div style="width:200px;background:#777;height:200px;display:inline-block;">
1
</div>
<div style="width:200px;background:#777;height:100px;display:inline-block;">
2
</div>
<br><br>
<div style="width:200px;background:#777;height:200px;display:inline-block;">
3
</div>
<div style="width:200px;background:#777;height:200px;display:inline-block;">
4
</div>
```

Как сделать что бы четвертый блок был сразу под вторым а не на уровне третьего?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Порядок немного другой получается, но это решение подойдет если нужна динамическая высота. [CSS Multi-column Layout](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp)

```css
.grid {
   columns: 2;
   column-gap: 10px;
}

.block {
   width: 200px;
   background: #777;
   height: 200px;
   display: inline-block;
   margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.block:nth-child(3) {
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="block">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        4
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так (1 ПРИМЕР). Это конечно не самый лучший способ, но по другому у меня не получилось. Просто добавил к 4-ому div перемещение на 100px вверх.

Либо по-другому (2 ПРИМЕР). Там еще один div с display: grid;, в котором все остальные div. Плюс уменьшенные margin сверху чтобы ровно было. Тоже не очень удобно, но работает.

```html
1 ПРИМЕР
<div style="width:200px;background:#777;height:200px;display:inline-block;">
  1
</div>
<div style="width:200px;background:#777;height:100px;display:inline-block;">
  2
</div>
<br><br>
<div style="width:200px;background:#777;height:200px;display:inline-block;">
  3
</div>
<div style="width:200px;background:#777;height:200px;display:inline-block; transform: translate(0px, -100px);">
  4
</div>

2 ПРИМЕР
<div style="width: 450px; display: grid;">
 <div style="width:200px;background:#777;height:200px;display:inline-block;">
  1
 </div>

 <div style="width:200px;background:#777;height:100px;display:inline-block; margin-left: 210px; margin-top: -200px">
  2
 </div>
 <div style="width:200px;background:#777;height:200px;display:inline-block; margin-top: 10px;">
  3
 </div>

 <div style="width:200px;background:#777;height:200px;display:inline-block; margin-left: 210px; margin-top: -300px;">
  4
 </div>
</div>
```